# Exclude C++ standard library function calls from gprof output

Tags: c++, profiling, gprof

I am using the C++ standard library in some C++ code and this makefile:

```
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -ggdb3 -std=c++11 -pedantic $(OTHERFLAGS)
cpp_sort: cpp_sort.o
    g++ -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $^
clean:
rm -rf *.o cpp_sort *~
```

The source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void get_input(vector<int>& items, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int element;
        cin >> element;
        items.push_back(element);
    }
}

void cpp_sort(vector<int>& items) {
    sort(items.begin(), items.end());
}

void print_array(vector<int>& items) {
    for (auto& item : items) {
        cout << item << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    vector<int> items;
    items.reserve(size);
    get_input(items, size);
    cpp_sort(items);
    print_array(items);
}
```

I call make like this:

```
make OTHERFLAGS=-pg
```

run the program (where large.txt is a long list of integers):

```
./cpp_sort <large.txt
```

and view the profiling information:

```
grof ./cpp_sort
```

Which is fine and it does work, but the calling of my functions is obscured by all the C++ standard library function calls.  Is there a way to exclude the standard library internal function calls?

Comment: What does "obscured by all the C++ standard library function calls" mean?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist in this example, the large number of std lib function calls in the gprof output crowds out the calls to the functions in the source file I wrote.  Nothing wrong with that per se, but for analysis purposes it would be good to focus in on 'my' functions.